# Keyboard language can't be changed for password (stuck on French)

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, password, internationalization, input-source

This issue started today, on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 (17F77).

Whenever I'm on a **password** field, my keyboard is switched to French and I can't change it!
[image]

This is extremely annoying, because I can't type any of my passwords using this input.

The only workaround I found today is to delete the French input source each time I need to input a password, then re-add the French input source afterward:
[image]

Please note that French isn't even my system Primary language, it's English:
[image]

Comment: Preferred language has nothing to do with keyboards, it governs app localization.

Comment: Have you tried a safe boot?  That can sometimes fix such glitches.

Comment: @TomGewecke I agree: just trying to find clues as for why, suddenly, after years of usage, password inputs anywhere on macos (system popups, browser fields) lock themselves to a French-only input. No: I haven't tried rebooting. I'll try tomorrow (computer is in office).

Comment: In the mean time, I've raised radar 41238116

Comment: Have you ever heard of anyone else with this problem?  May be hard to duplicate. Safe boot is more than reboot, see https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25617  Also you should check whether same problem exists when you create a new account.  If not, it's probably a broken .plist file in your main account.

Comment: @TomGewecke problem **not** solved in Safe Mode. Problem **not** solved with a new account.